# python 2.7 how to change sys.displayhook back to default

Tags: python, unicode

For `a = u'\u4e00'` if I type `a` in the console, I get: `u'\u4e00'`. So to display `a` as the unicode character, I can change the sys.displayhook as follows:

```
import sys
def my_display(x):
    if isinstance(x, unicode):
        sys.stdout.write(x.encode("utf-8"))
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(repr(x))
    sys.stdout.write("\n")

sys.displayhook = my_display
```

Then if I type `a` in the console I get `一`.

The question: if after that, I want to change the sys.displayhook back to the original default setting. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sys.displayhook = sys.__displayhook__
```

[`sys.__displayhook__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.__displayhook__) stores the original `sys.displayhook` for cases like this.

(By the way, I would also advise not doing your original `sys.displayhook` replacement. You probably just want `print a`, maybe with something to match the encoding to your terminal's encoding.)